# python opencv: cannot capture a window

Tags: python, opencv, webcam

Sorry I paste mirror parts at worng place, and as frame is null during mirror part, I made it into a comment while running

**Looks like my cap.read() can't read anything**

This is really a simple python code of opencv for just capturing a window and make webcamera work. But when I ran it, no window shown but no bugs shown either. How can I know what's wrong readily?

How can I know if the webcamera is 0 or sth else?
Why the mirror part doesn't work?
Could someone recommend me some good examples for opencv on python?
Thank you!!

```
import cv2

def capture_camera(mirror=True, size=None):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        #if mirror is True:
            #frame = frame[:,::-1]
        if size is not None and len(size) == 200:
            frame = cv2.resize(frame, size)
            cv2.imshow('camera capture', frame)
            k = cv2.waitKey(100)
            if k == 27: 
                break
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

capture_camera()
```

Comment: Check if `ret` is `True` or `False` and whether `cap.isOpened` returns `True`. Most likely, OpenCV can not find your webcam.

Comment: Thank you I think you're right looks like both ret and frame are null, or the mirror part won't throw a TypeError...how can I fix it? Could you please tell me more details?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not executiong below if statement

```
    if size is not None and len(size) == 200:
```

because size is tuple and len(size) will return 2 since you defined

```
     size = (800,600)
```

2nd mistake : you were changing frame array before it is initialized.
first you need to get frame array which is returned by **cap.read()** then you can check if mirror is True if yes then reverse the array by frame = frame[:,::-1]

try this code  :

```
import cv2

def capture_camera(mirror=True, size=None):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if mirror is True:
           frame = frame[:,::-1]

        size = (800,600)
        if size is not None:
            frame = cv2.resize(frame, size)
            cv2.imshow('camera capture', frame)
            k = cv2.waitKey(100)
            if k == 27:
                break
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

capture_camera()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was my fault for pasting a wrong code....looks like my cap.read() is null and I don't know why....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34716709/4287377 here op solved it by recompiling ffmpeg library..

Answer (score -1):

Try this code. It works for me:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('Webcam (close with q)' ,frame)

    if(cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q')):
       break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

BTW:
Your code throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python/Scripts/OpenCV/Scripts/so_test.py", line 21, in <module>
capture_camera()
File "C:/Python/Scripts/OpenCV/Scripts/so_test.py", line 7, in capture_camera
frame = frame[:,::-1]
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'frame' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Your code does exactly the same thing as the original code in the question. And there is zero need to import numpy, since you are not using it here at all.

Comment: Not saying your code is bad (it's not), but it doesn't answer the question, since it is not improving on the original code (they do the same thing), or tries to explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sorry I pasted wrong one..... But I'll try yours!